# excel vba: transparency in chchart

Tags: excel, bar-chart, userform, vba

I try to find a solution for setting the color in a user-forms bar chart (`chchart`) transparent. The approach for regular bar charts doesn't work:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6) 
  .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbBlue  ' <-- "Format"property doesn't exist in "chchart"
  .Format.Fill.Transparency = 0.9 
End With
```

It looks like there is no transparency property for a `chchart`. Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. The OWC pre-dates the time when you could set a transparency on a chart in the regular way, and you can't copy and paste transparent shapes onto an OWC series.

Comment: Hello Roy, what does "OWC" mean?

Comment: Office Web Components - it's the library that contains the controls you're using.

Comment: Ok, that's very sad and I have to live with that but how can I accept your comment as an answer to make you happy at the end?